# Hide android keyboard on swipe down

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to hide the android keyboard on swipe down? I want that if keyboard is open and if user swipe down on screen then keyboard should hide. How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to implement **onTouchListener** to your view and then on scroll down event make keyboard hide like this

```
/**
     * Hide Keyboard
     *
     * @param activity
     */
    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        try {
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

*OnSwipeTouchListener.java*:

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } 
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MyActivity.this) {
    public void onSwipeTop() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
```

Comment: How I can get the swipe event from top to bottom from where I will call the HideKeyboard method? I tried with OnTouchEvent but its not working

Comment: @anand i edited my answer please check and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now its working. In xamarin we have DispatchTouchEvent that we call for getting touch event. Now keyboard close whenever user swipes.

Comment: @anand Glad it help you. Please accept it as answer and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SimpleOnGestureListener()` and override it's `onFling()` method to detect swipes. For a swipe down you compare the `MotionEvent`'s delta in Y with sensitivity.

```
  public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        try {
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

     SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {

       float sensitivity = 50; //suit yourself

       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       if((e2.getY() - e1.getY()) > sensitivity){
        //swiped down, now do whatever you want.
        hideKeyboard();
       }
      }
     }
```